# Can Gyarados be found in the wild?

Tags: pokemon-go

For several pokémon I found their evolutions in the wild. For example Tentacruel, Raticate and Pidgeotto. I was wondering if Gyarados maybe is an exception because of the exceptional  high evolve cost of Magikarp? I can imagine that they really want you to evolve a Magikarp in this case. So, has anyone found a wild one yet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Gyarados is accessible in the wild.

As it does not have a [rarity class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf)<sup>1</sup> (note the `PokemonClass` on Mew or Mewtwo) assigned to it, it may spawn freely (albeit rarely) across the world.

However, due to their spawn chances, it may not be as much work to evolve a Magikarp -- unless you're exceedingly lucky and near one of the [biomes](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884) in the game that supports Gyarados.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The data sourced in the above dump came from packet and game reverse-engineering and has since been validated by many people, including myself. It is perhaps, as of now, the best source of information we have on what makes Pokemon tick.</sup>

Comment: surley it's not so rare that you would run into *100 magikarp* before finding it

Comment: thats odd. that data lists squirtle as "family_rattata"

Comment: @Timelord64 I've run into a fair amount near the beach, and blame Niantic for the naming.

Comment: I can confirm that several of the states parks near my mothers' house that have a small river running through them spawn Gyarados

Comment: I have evolved Magikarp into Gyarados twice but have yet to see any in the wild. I live very close to the sea... so many Magikarp :-/

Comment: I was powering up a my recently evolved first and only Gyarados on my way to put it in a gym. My phone buzzed and I had a look...it was a wild Gyarados (430cp) after two hyper-balls, it ran

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find Gyarados in the wild, although it is very rare. There have been a couple of sightings, here in Australia. It has also been registered in at least two different instances, on [a collective spreadsheet for listing Pokemon locations in Sydney](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQb8eLnkOOF1loQ5wU-_cRnOpTKwHjVzOouAIyfSnuM/htmlview?sle=true)<sup>1</sup>.

```
#130    Gyarados    Darling Harbour, Circular Quay
```

Gyrados is rarer than Magikarp, but consider that you need 400 Magikarp Candy to evolve a Magikarp. **If** you find a location accessible to you, that is known to spawn a Gyarados, it would be arguably more efficient than attempting to catch 100 Magikarp.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Be aware that the creator, one *Bradley Dowling*, has been updating this list. However, for reasons that are lost on me, he made it available to *anonymous public edit*. The list, itself, is often stripped and vandalised. You have to revert to the last version posted by the original author to read through the legitimate list.</sub>