# Fastest scenario for evolving pokemon such as Magikarp (400 candies)?

Tags: pokemon-go

Magikarp (and some others?) require at least 400 candies to evolve. The obvious way to evolve a Magikarp is to catch 101 wild Magikarp (which would take me about 0.5 years).

Thus far, I've *caught* 1 (maybe 2) Magikarp and *hatched* 1. My current candy level is **13**. And, I'm not sure why it is 13.

**strategy for evolving Magikarp**
1. Hatch as many eggs as possible, and hope for a Magikarp (that seemed to yield 10 candies).
2. And of course, catch as many in the wild as possible.

What else can I do to accelerate the evolution of my Magikarp?

Comment: Catching a Magikarp gives 3 candies and transfering another 1. So to evolve one you don't need 400 Magikarp but only 100

Comment: It's really 101. You can't transfer all of them, because you need to keep one to evolve.

Comment: Go somewhere near water, I already have about 120 candies w/o spamming too much pokemon

Comment: I think this would have worked during the water festival. On other days I've tried this. Doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The quickest way I have experience to catch Magikarp is to locate a Pokestop next to a body of water. With the combination of a Luremodule and an Incense, I have witnessed people "fishing" for Magikarp. I sat there and a Magikarp was spawning roughly every 2 minutes

Comment: Literal fishing, who could've imagined that?

Comment: There's a famous spot in my town with 3 Pokéstops, which are always lured since there's at times hundreds of people playing there. Magikarps come in multiples every minute, as well as water Pokémon. If you're able to find something like that you'll only need a couple of hours.

Comment: There's a spot like that near me too. I got over 100 candy without even trying.

Answer (score 37):

There's [evidence that Gyarados can be found in the wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/275397/141706), so if you can manage that, you don't even have to evolve your Magikarp at all. Hang out around lakes, harbours and the seaside and you might get lucky (in the meantime, you'll probably catch Magikarp anyway).

Other than that though, the only way is to catch 101 Magikarp, transfer at least 97 of them<sup>1</sup>, and then evolve 1 of them. You don't need 400 of them, because you get 3 candies for each catch and 1 for each transfer.

Eggs could help (Magikarp can hatch from 2km eggs, and you'll get much more than 3 candies for a hatch), but given the odds of 14 different Pokemon that can hatch from a 2km egg, you'll probably find it faster to specifically focus on catching Magikarp near bodies of water. If you hatch one... bonus :)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks [xehpuk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/156791/xehpuk) for the [maths help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275791/fastest-scenario-for-evolving-pokemon-such-as-magikarp-400-candies#comment387494_275814) ;)</sub>

Comment: It seemed to me that the hatched magikarp yielded me several more candies than the one which I caught. But, I definitely could be wrong.

Comment: @khyle Yes that's definitely the case. I've edited my answer to clarify that. I think still though that given the 1 in 14 chance of hatching a Magikarp, you'll still get more candy _overall_ by focusing on catching rather than hatching :)

Comment: I assume the additional candies from hatching is because of the chance that if you just hatched a rare that doesn't spawn near you, finding NONE AT ALL ever again would be really frustrating for leveling it up.

Comment: You only need to transfer 97 of the 101 Magikarps.

Comment: @xehpuk Good point. Your arithmetic skills are outstanding, mostly because you *actually used them*.

Comment: @xehpuk Hahaha good work. I've edited the answer

Comment: Now that Pinap Berries are available, the math is even more favorable. Catching 58 Magikarp (with Pinap berries on at least 57 of them) and transferring 57 of those will be the shortest route now, leaving out the possibilities of wild Gyarados or egg hatching.

Answer (score 0):

I put a magikarp as my buddy. That way I get one candy per km walked! I am up to 80.

Comment: The question asked for the fastest scenario... I've had the game since July 6th and I've only walked 263km. Walking 400km is much slower than any other method.

Comment: Unless you are not conveniently near water areas, in which case, having a Magikarp buddy would be the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

I would just go near a body of water and hang there...
If there is a pokestop, double luck! If you are going on a vacay to a beach, fully charge your device, and get out there!